# ServiceStack /views sub-folders

Tags: razor, servicestack

I have a View folder structure such as:

- Home

  - Home.cshtml
  - Settings.cshtml

When I have the pages directly in my /Views/ folder, I can do the following:

```
public class HomeService : Service
{


[View("Home")]
    public object Any(Home request)
    {
        return new HomeResponse();
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to tell my Service to serve the views from a sub-folder? Even better if I can define some folder object, and be able to define my views as normal:

However when I have my views in a sub-folder, I cannot do the following:

```
public class HomeService : Service
{
    [View("Home/Home")]
    public object Any(Home request)
    {
        return new HomeResponse();
    }
}
```

Any idea how to get my Service to serve views from a sub-folder? Even better if I can define the folder seperately, and use:

```
[View("Home")]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All View names inside ServiceStack `/Views` folder should be uniquely named (i.e. like Request DTO's). So inside the `/Views` folder it can be in any folder structure you like since they're  all unique ServiceStack will just pick the view with the matching name.